# cropping snapshot in react native maps to just routes

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, stylesheet

I would like to know if anyone knows how to take snapshot of just routes in react native maps, something what ride sharing companies have when a user views previous trips. I am able to take a snapshot using the code below, though I noticed the height, width, region properties do not.

```
         takeLocationSnapshot() {
            const { location: { longitude, latitude, } } = this.state;

            const snapshot = this.mapView.takeSnapshot({
              width: 300,      // optional, when omitted the view-width is used
              height: 300,     // optional, when omitted the view-height is used
              region: {
                latitude,
                longitude,
                LONGITUDEDELTA,
                LATITUDEDELTA,
              },
              // iOS only, optional region to render
              format: 'jpg',   // image formats: 'png', 'jpg' (default: 'png')
              quality: 0.7,    // image quality: 0..1 (only relevant for jpg, default: 1)
              result: 'file'   // result types: 'file', 'base64' (default: 'file')
            });
            snapshot.then((uri) => {
              this.props.locationSnapshotChange(uri);
            });
        }


   <View style={styles.imageContentWrap}>
    <Image
     source={imageSource}
     style={styles.imageStyle}
   />
  </View>
imageContentWrap: {
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  flex: 0.58,
},
imageStyle: {
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  resizeMode: 'cover',
  overflow: 'hidden',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using Wrapper with *fixed height and overflow hidden*, and add *position absolute, top property* to styles of your image